# ASP.net dynamic grid of textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have 2 lists of strings and I'd like to dynamically create a grid of textboxes:

```
List<string> X = {"A", "B", "C"};
List<string> Y = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

          A     B     C
     1   TBX   TBX   TBX
     2   TBX   TBX   TBX
     3   TBX   TBX   TBX
     4   TBX   TBX   TBX

     [Button]
```

When I enter data into the textboxes and click the button, I'd like to be able to iterate over these textboxes and determine the "X" and "Y" coordinates associated with each textbox.

I can probably figure out how to dynamically create this grid of textboxes, but I think I'll run into issues when I post the data.  How do I get the values from the dynamically created textboxes after a postback?

I'll have no issue doing the iteration and actual logic but I can't figure out how to get the data into a container so that it can be iterated.  Will I have to dynamically create the textboxes again while reading the posted data?  What does that look like?

Comment: Web Forms.  This is sort of a data entry hack for entering tubular data.  There is gonna be javascript stuff that does some parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach. You can have a place holder in the asp.net page. In code behind dynamically create a table with dynamic text boxes and insert it inside place holder. In this instance you have control over the ID of each textbox. On post back values entered into the text boxes will be retained (since IDs are definite you can do javascript manipulation as well)

**Here is the aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DynamicControls.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test2.DynamicControls" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PHDynamicTable" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test2
{
    public partial class DynamicControls : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            CreateTextBoxesInTable();
        }

        private void CreateTextBoxesInTable()
        {
            PHDynamicTable.Controls.Clear();

            List<string> X = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
            List<string> Y = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = "dynamicTable";

            TableRow tr;
            foreach (string y in Y)
            {
                tr = new TableRow();

                foreach (string x in X)
                { 
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();

                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.ID = "txt_" + x + y;
                    tc.Controls.Add(textBox);

                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(tr);
            }

            PHDynamicTable.Controls.Add(table);
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PHDynamicTable.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                Table dynamicTable = (Table)PHDynamicTable.FindControl("dynamicTable");
                if (dynamicTable != null)
                {
                    foreach (TableRow tr in dynamicTable.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
                        {
                            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)tc.Controls[0];
                            string text = textBox.Text;
                            //Do whatever you want with the control
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Few screen shots**

input screen with data

[image]

on postback (submit)

[image]

after submit

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I basically started down this path, but the way you did it is way cleaner.

Comment: I thought this looked ideal for what I'm doing, but PHDynamicTable is 'nothing' if I call CreateTextBoxesInTable from OnPreInit. If I call it from Page_Load in the 'If Not IsPostback' clause, the table disappears after I click my update button. I'm having to delve into the order of page load events. Probably no bad thing.

Comment: @user910683 Probably you should have seen this; but again FYI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events

Comment: Thanks Prashanth. I did look at that and it helped me to determine that what I needed was OnPreLoad. I'm using VB.NET not C# (not by choice!) so my code is not exactly the same as the code given. It's a direct translation though, and my understanding is that the order of lifecycle events is not affected by language used.

Answer (score 2):

Usability issues aside, I am going to assume that you are in ASP.NET Webforms and not ASP.NET MVC. In webforms, this becomes kind of an nightmare. You could certainly nest two  controls. One control's datasource becomes the first list, and the second datasource is the second list. Then in the secondary repeater template you put your asp:textbox. However, the ID here even if set explicitly will actually be a generated value because a repeater is what's known in ASP.nET Webforms as a naming container; which means that the values of the IDs will be changed at runtime.

On postback you can iterate over the control tree of the parent repeater to find the child repeater. Then in the child repeater you can iterate over that repeater's controls to find your textboxes. something like:

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:repeater>
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:textbox />
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:repeater>   
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Then in the code behind, on Post Back [pseudo-code]

```
foreach(Control c in myTopRepeater.Controls){
    if(c == RepeaterControl) //is of type repeater. again, pseudo code
    {
         foreach(Control subC in c)
         {
             if(subC == textBox)
             {
                 //Compare generated name, etc to my Lists

             }
         }
    }
}
```

It might help to read up on naming containers. You can get a predictable naming setup, but it's not 100% intuitive.
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Yes this is how I'd recommend doing it in Web Forms.